# Use multi-finger gestures with RealVNC

Tags: remote-desktop, android

I am using RealVNC for remote access to my Mac from my Android phone. I am also using it for controlling the cursor - like a trackpad. I want to use the multi-finger gestures like mission control, app exposé, etc. Is that possible via RealVNC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RealVNC Android app mouse interaction mode doesn't support macOS specific multi-finger gestures. For the list of supported mouse actions see the support article:

- [How do I use VNC Viewer for Android and iOS? - RealVNC Help Center](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018541231-How-do-I-use-VNC-Viewer-for-Android-and-iOS-)

> [image]

Comment: Isn't there any plugin or anything that can do it?

Comment: @VictorF It would be advisable to contact the vendor for support regarding non-advertised features.